# How to trust self-signed certificate with Node.js

Tags: node.js, macos, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have generated a self-signed certificate and I am using it with Node.js with

```
const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem')
};

const server = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port %d in %s mode', app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
});
```

I am able to access https://localhost:3000, but Chrome says that the url is 'Not Secure'. I have tried to make Chrome trust the certificate by first adding the certificate to Keychain Access in Mac OSX and then clicking it to say "Always Trust" in "When using this certificate", but it keeps saying that the URL is not secure.

## Edit

I have followed many different tutorials to make Chrome trust my self-signed certificate.

I have added the certificate in Keychain Access (both to `login` and `System`). I have updated the certificate to tell the OS to always trust the certificate.

I have restarted my computer, Chrome, and Node.js server, but it still says that the connection is not secure.

I have no idea what I have done wrong.

## Edit 2

It says that the certificate is trusted, so it might be configured wrong.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)

Comment: I have also followed instructions in this question, but it is still not secure

Comment: Interesting. What does Chrome say about the certificate in the security panel in devtools?

Comment: It says both `There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).` and `The certificate for this site does not contain a Subject Alternative Name extension containing a domain name or IP address.`. My common name is `localhost` and I'm visiting localhost at `https://localhost:3000`

Comment: Ah, looks like you're running into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42917227/4220785